# Mongodb, mongoose. Error: Connection was destroyed by application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my code I have such error:

> Error: Connection was destroyed by application

The code below works just one first time:

```
User.find(function (err, user) {
console.log('User.create');
    if (err) 
    {
        console.log('USERERROR: ' + err + ' user ' + user);
        doneUserBase(fn,act,idC);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('ID: ' +  ' user ' + user);
        doneUserBase(fn,act,idC);
    }
  });
```

How to fix it?